# Number as column in SQLAlchemy query

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

How can I express the column "c" in SQL query like this:

```
SELECT a, b, 0 AS c
FROM mytable
```

SQLAlchemy code:

```
session.query(mytable.c.a, mytable.c.b, {???, c is a dynamic column})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal_column
session.query(mytable.c.a, mytable.c.b, literal_column(u'0').label(u'c'))
```